# JSP container for embedded systems

Tags: beagle-bone

There is this project I am working on which is using a BeagleBone and we need a JSP container to run on it. I was thinking of Tomcat but wanted to know if Tomcat is suitable for embedded systems.

Is it too resource-heavy? If yes, are there other lighter JSP containers? I know only of Tomcat and Jetty.

Comment: and why u need the JSP container there. provide more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you perhaps elaborate on your performance requirements?

I'm quite confident you will be able to get Tomcat running, [here's a video of someone getting Tomcat 5.5 running](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUCa8GQvsjo) on a beagleboard c4 (note the video is dated Feb 2011). Also remember that you can run a normal [Ubuntu distro](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM) on the beaglebone, so installing Tomcat should be as easy as simply going 'sudo apt-get install tomcat7'.

The big issue is performance. If you're planning to use the beaglebone as a server handling thousands of requests a second you're probably going to have a problem.

The following table indicates the performance difference between embedded application processors and a desktop PC (the benchmark calculates pi to 500 digits, [see Johannes Ernst's blog for more info](http://upon2020.com/blog/2013/07/comparing-raspberry-pi-beaglebone-and-mirabox/)).

[image]

The above benchmark obviously does not characterize other performance areas important in running a server (e.g. disk or network I/O), but let's assume you're looking at roughly a tenfold increase in processing time.

For instance, if a single Tomcat transaction usually took 10 ms to complete, it could now take 100 ms. If you're only using the beaglebone to serve a small number of consumers (infrequently), and responsiveness isn't as critical, it should work fine.

Comment: It won't be connected to the Internet but to a local network. So, probably tens of requests a second. That should be fine right?

Comment: I honestly can't say, it depends on what your servlet is up to. Are you planning on running a full blown sql db in the background, or are you just buffering data collected by the beaglebone? Ultimately the only way of knowing is test and see.

Comment: We plan to use an SQLite backend